# implementing search bar on tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have made the single view application .I am trying to implement the search in table view My program is crashing at

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     /*crashing  */ let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "discoveryNewscell") as! DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell  //////crashing 
        cell.newsSneakerImage.image=sneakers[indexPath.row].image
        cell.newsTitle.text=sneakers[indexPath.row].news

        return cell


    }
```

How to implement the search bar Search operation in table view ? You can download the sample code from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e4SuFbZLq7fOUeuJc59wYfIMvas3cJ-a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Rechek your cellId in storyboard also as it is same as **discoveryNewscell** or not.

Comment: yes they are same

Comment: specify your crash reason.

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10d2e0778) to 'DiscoveryNewsTableViewCell'

Comment: Remove `self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "discoveryNewscell")` from `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Removing self.DiscoveryNewsTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "discoveryNewscell") from viewDidLoad() -->is working for displaying the table view and search bar. how to perform the search ?

Comment: @ajadka search code not working check it

Comment: How to implement the search code ?

Comment: Follow this tutorial for integrating searchView in TableView: 
https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: i have implemented this tutorial   http://www.seemuapps.com/swift-search-bar-tutorial .   but it not working .see where is the mistake

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 1):

You have done mistake in cellID, It is different from storyboard.

I replaced the cellID from `cellForRow` & `Storyboard` to **cellNew** & runned your project & it worked.

Check output or your app,

[image]

Comment: Search is not working .How to search through table view